# Grease/lubricate rubber stabilizer bar bushings?

Tags: suspension, lubrication, bushing, rubber

I just bought a set of [these bushings](https://partsonline.mevotech.com/details/MK90560) to replace the worn-out ones in my front stabilizer bar.  The set did not include any grease or lubricant.  The manufacturer doesn't state the construction material, but they smell like tires/rubber.

Do they need to be lubricated before installation?  If so, what type of lubricant should I use?

Comment: Be careful of using petroleum products on rubber parts. Petroleum degrades rubber. See, for example, [What Chemicals Are Harmful to Rubber Seals?](https://sciencing.com/list-7498602-chemicals-harmful-rubber-seals.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the seldom cases I saw them the manual advised to use soapy water to install them as petroleum based lubes degrade rubber. Normally grease is included on items that need it. Make sure to torque down the bushings carrier as the stabilizer bar is in the "work" position, that is the position the stabilizer bar has when the loaded (normally only the driver) vehicle rests on the wheels.

Comment: Might want to also mention that using petroleum-based lubricants on rubber bushings will likely reduce their lifespan.

Comment: Even if it lubricant doesn't harm the rubber, it will squeeze out of the "joint" and collect dirt, which will tend to corrode the metal. When they are clamped tight the only thing that moves is the rubber itself flexing, so there is nothing to lubricate.

Comment: @Martin: can you clarify what you mean by work position?  I was just going to replace one at a time so it would remain "attached" to the frame while replacing each bushing.

Comment: @Martin: thanks, when I got under the car, it became clear what you were referring to with "work" position.